# prevent multi-thread application from termination when one of its thread performs an illegal operation

Tags: c++, multithreading

Is it possible to prevent a multi-thread application from getting terminated when one of its thread performs an illegal operation like integer divide by zero operation. This is a sample code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>

void thread1() {
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(2));
    for (int i = 3; i >= 0; --i)
        std::cout << (3 / i) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "thread end" << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    std::thread t(thread1);
    t.detach();

    std::cout << "before sleep\n";
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(5));
    //t.join();
    std::cout << "after sleep\n";
}
```

In the above code I'm trying a integer divide by zero operation in a thread which is causing the whole program from getting terminated.

Comment: Division by zero (in integer arithmetic) is hardware fault. If you use Microsoft compiler you could turn such exception into SEH exception - then it can be caught by `try/catch` C++ block, which you can put in your thread function to catch such exception.

Comment: @rafix07 Not a C++ `try`/`catch` block, but a special SEH [`__try`/`__except`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/try-except-statement?view=msvc-170) statement.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude you can have try/catch setup to catch SEH. But it's a really bad setting to have. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/eh-exception-handling-model?view=msvc-170 and the `a` option. FYI to readers DO NOT use the `a` option for `/EH` on msvc.

Comment: Well, I had one app delivered that did exactly that - trapped all exceptions, including SEH, before thet escaped the thread at the outermost 'while(true)' loop.  For two years, customers got 'Access violation' text lines in the app log with no noticed ill-effects.  It was not ideal, but it kept the app up.  Eventually, I found/fixed the root cause and the errors disappeared:)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, in general that isn't possible; all threads in a process share the same memory space, which means that a fatal error in any one thread might have corrupted the data structures of anything else in the process, therefore the whole process is terminated.

If you really need your program to be able to survive a fatal error, then the problematic code needs to be executed inside a separate child process, so that when it crashes, the parent process can survive (and maybe re-launch a new child process, or whatever is appropriate).  But in general the preferred approach is simply to make sure that your code doesn't contain any bugs that would lead to crashes.